# MDI Application in java

Tags: java, swing, mdi, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I am making a MDI application in java using netbeans.
the issue is that i have two buttons: Add employee and search employee. When i click Add employee, the internal frame for add employee opens up in the desktop pane, and when i click search employee it gets behind the earlier frame and is not visible until i exit the first frame. I want that if desktop pane is not empty then earlier internal frame should be disposed on click of the other button. Plese help me out

This is the code: Here JP is variable name for desktop pane.

```
private void BAddEmpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        o=new EntryEmp();
        JP.add(o);
        o.setVisible(true);  
    }                                       

    private void BSearchEmpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Employee_search ob1=new Employee_search();
        JP.add(ob1);
        ob1.setVisible(true);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to set the first panes visibility to false:

```
private void BSearchEmpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Employee_search ob1=new Employee_search();
    JP.add(ob1);
    ob1.setVisible(true);
    if (o != null && o.getVisible == true){
        o.setVisible(false);
        //and possibly kill it:
        o = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've added the new `JInternalFrame` and made it visible call [`JInternalFrame#toFront`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#toFront--)